# JS go trough object and check if another object contains its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to go trough JS object (1) to find out if value exists on another object (2) and return object (2) found value.

```
var returnObj = [];
    selectedValues.forEach(function(value, key){
        var found = valuesObject.some(function (el) {
            if (el.item_id === value){
                return el.item_id;
            }
        });
        console.log(found);
    });
```

in this case I can only find out if its exists or not by getting true/false and I've also tried this

```
var returnObj = [];
    selectedValues.forEach(function(value, key){
        console.log(_.intersection(valuesObject, value));
    });
```

but in this case it returns me only empty arrays instead of object (2) value which was found by object (1) value

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `return` inside of an `.forEach` call, you will only return out of the callback you passed to the `forEach` function, not your enclosing function. You can use a standard for-loop, where you can return out of.

Assuming you have a list of "values" you want to find in the second object:

```
const values = [/*...*/];

Object.keys(secondObject).forEach(key => {
  const value = secondObject[key];

  if (values.includes(value)) {
    /* secondObject has a property with the values you are looking for */
  }
});
```

`Object.keys` gives you an array of property keys of an object. Depending on your environment you can also use `Object.values()`, this will return you an array of values (not keys) for a given object.

Comment: but its still not answered how to find object property by value

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple and basic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesObject.length; j++) {
        if (selectedValues[i] === valuesObject[j].item_id) {
            return valuesObject[j].item_id;
        }
    }
}
```

If you prefer one line:

```
return selectedValues.length && selectedValues.map(value => valuesObject.find(v => v.item_id === value))[0]
```

Comment: yeah i think its the best solution since I was trying to find something faster

Comment: If you want something "shorter", I have added it to my answer. But it's not faster.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've got the setup wrong, but seeing `returnObj` is an array, `filter`ing seems to be a good option. For example in combination with a `Set`:

```
let set = new Set(valuesObject.map(o=>o.item_id)),
    returnObj = selectedValues.filter(s=>set.has(s));
```

Example:

```js
let selectedValues = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'],
 valuesObject = [ {item_id:'ddd'}, {item_id:'eee'}, {item_id:'bbb'}];


let set = new Set(valuesObject.map(o=>o.item_id)),
 returnObj = selectedValues.filter(s=>set.has(s));

console.log(returnObj);
```